# Delete calender entries

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to delete all the  calender entries. I am using this query for fetching calender entries

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events");
cursor =  context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null,null, null);
```

But cursor returns null each time. I also checked it with 
`Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://calendar/events");`   But result is same.

Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the targeted API level? (The calender API is not standardized before API level 14 / Android 4.0).

Comment: Targeted api is api Level 8 and above.

Answer (score 0):

//try this req `android:minSdkVersion="7"`

```
public void deleteAllCalendar(){
        Log.i(TAG, "In deleteAllCalendar()");
        String strUriEvents = "content://calendar/events";
        Uri uri_calendar = Uri.parse(strUriEvents);
        String str_column_name = "_id";
        String[] projection = {str_column_name};
        int columnIndex = 0;
        String str_id = "";
        Vector<String> vector_id = new Vector<String>();
        int delRow = 0;
        String where = "";
        try {
            Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri_calendar, projection, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(str_column_name);
                    str_id = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    vector_id.add(str_id);
                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
            for(int i=0; i<vector_id.size(); i++){
                str_id = vector_id.get(i);
                where = str_column_name+"="+str_id;
                delRow = cr.delete(uri_calendar, where, null);
                Log.i(TAG, "deleteAllCalendar(),delRow:"+delRow);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "deleteAllCalendar(),Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Out deleteAllCalendar()");
    }
```

Comment: it is also giving null in cursor.

Comment: @unflagged.destination did U add READ_CALENDAR & WRITE_CALENDAR Allows an application to write (but not read) the user's calendar data. permission in your manifest.xml

Comment: Yes, but same result in cursor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the calendar authority as part of the URI. It is not standardized before API level 14. If you target level 8 and above `com.android.calendar` is suggested by Google's code but the phone's manufacturer may use another authority. Before API 8 the authority is just `calendar` (as used in the previous answer).

Also remember to grant permission to write to the user's calendar.

When you delete the events remember to delete their extended properties, reminders, and alerts as well. Here are their paths:

```
private static final String calendarPath = "calendars";
private static final String eventsPath = "events";
private static final String remindersPath = "reminders";
private static final String calAlertsPath = "calendar_alerts";
private static final String eventsExtPropPath = "extendedproperties";
```

With API level 14 this is standardized and you can get the URI from `CalendarContract`:

```
    CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI;
    CalendarContract.Reminders.CONTENT_URI;
    CalendarContract.CalendarAlerts.CONTENT_URI;
    CalendarContract.ExtendedProperties.CONTENT_URI;
```

Comment: Yes i checked with both the URI but always cursor gives null

Comment: Did you check the mentioned permission (calendar read for now)?

Comment: Yes, but cursor returns null.